# Status bar notification, phonegap pushplugin

Tags: android, cordova

I'm implementing an android application with phonegap and I'm using the PushPlugin plugin to have notifications. By now I have only the alert message and the notification on the lockscreen. I would like to have a banner in the status bar like the one in the image.

Image: http://postimg.org/image/ebipw0s49/

How can I do this?
Here's my code:

```
            onNotification = function (e){
            //        function onNotification(e) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {

                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                regid = {'reg':e.regid};
    //                    console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                //sending the regId to the server
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'http://192.168.0.11:5000/api/v1.0/register_id',
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    data:JSON.stringify(regid),
                    success: function(){
                        alert('registration OK');
                    }
                });

            }
            break;

            case 'message':
            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
            // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
            if (e.foreground)
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                alert(e.payload.title + e.payload.message);
                // on Android soundname is outside the payload.
                // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                //var soundfile = e.payload.sound;
                // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                //var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);
                //my_media.play();
            }
            else
            {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                if (e.coldstart)
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    alert(e.payload.title + e.payload.message);
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    alert(e.payload.title + e.payload.message);
                }
            }
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TITLE: ' + e.payload.title + '</li>');
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
            break;

            case 'error':
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg +               '</li>');
            break;

            default:
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How notifications are displayed is up to the Operating System itself. The image you are displaying is the notification system of Android Lollipop (5.0). If you want these kind of notifications make sure to update your phone to Android Lollipop.

Comment: The image that I posted is a screenshot from my phone